# how do you open an FBX file on blender 2.49?

Tags: import

i have quite a difficulty on opening an FBX on the old version of blender. help

Comment: 2.49 is quite an old version--at least 8 years, and while I don't know how much support, either natively, or via add-ons there was for import of files in fbx format, is it possible that you are trying to import an fbx file compliant with  newer version of the fbx standard than is supported by 2.49?

Comment: why the need for 2.49 specifically? you could try the oldest 2.5+ version that imports that fbx, then try to save as .blend and open that with 2.49. Blender is somewhat forward-compatible, and so was 2.49, but some feature could be not supported though.